# Избавиться от Unnecessary boxing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть такой код

```
int i = 5;
Double d = Double.valueOf(i);
```

(на самом деле код такой

```
int getInt() {
  ....
}

Double d = Double.valueOf(getInt());
```

но не суть)

На строку

```
Double d = Double.valueOf(i);
```

IDEA пишет

> Warning: Unnecessary boxing.

Но какой же он Unnecessary, если мне нужно примитив int привести к объекту Double?

На строку

```
Double d = i
```

я уже получаю ошибку

> Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.Double Found: int

Это баг анализатора, или все-таки как-то можно присвоение переписать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примитивный тип `int` нужно сначала привести к примитивному типу `double` - после этого `boxing` уже не нужен

```
Double d = (double) i;
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня IDEA пишет также. Если возможно, то используйте такой вариант:

```java
Integer i = 5;
Double d = getInt().doubleValue();
```

Либо используйте, как IDEA и предлагает:

```java
Double d = (double) getInt();
```